# How to kill android application using android code?

Tags: android

I am develoing small android application in eclipse. In that project i kill the running process in android, i got the Permission Denial error. how can i solve this problem in android. 
Anybody help for this problem....
THIS IS MY CODE

```
package com.example.nuts;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.*;

public class killprocess extends Activity
{
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();    
Recivesms rms=new Recivesms();
String Number="";
int pid=0;
String appname="";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    try
    {           
        Number=Recivesms.senderNum;
        pid=Integer.parseInt(Recivesms.struid);
        appname=getAppName(pid);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"App Name is "+appname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
         ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            if (processes != null){
                for (int i=0; i<processes.size(); i++){
                    RunningAppProcessInfo temp = processes.get(i);
                    String pName = temp.processName;

                    if (pName.equals(appname))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"App Name is matched  "+appname+" "+pName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                            int pid1 = android.os.Process.getUidForName(pName);
                            //android.os.Process.killProcess(pid1);
                            am.killBackgroundProcesses(pName);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Killed successfully....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    }
             }
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(Number, null,"Your process Successfully killed..." , null,null);     
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
    private String getAppName(int Pid)
    {
        String processName = "";
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        Iterator i = l.iterator();
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        while(i.hasNext()) 
        {
                  ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
          try 
          { 
              if(info.pid == Pid)
              {
                  CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                  //Log.d("Process", "Id: "+ info.pid +" ProcessName: "+    info.processName +"  Label: "+c.toString());
                          //processName = c.toString();
                      processName = info.processName;
                  }
              }
              catch(Exception e) 
              {
                    //Log.d("Process", "Error>> :"+ e.toString());
              }
       }
        return processName;
    }
 }
```

After executing the code. i got the following error...

```
Permission Denial:
killBackgroundProcess() from pid=894,
uid=10052 requires
android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
```

Also i put the following line on manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESS" />
```

Anybody help for how to solve this problem...
Thanking you....

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nuts"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESS" ></uses-permission>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/clip1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nuts.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nuts.createpassword"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nuts.editpassword"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nuts.processList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nuts.killprocess"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

         >

    </activity>
   <receiver android:name=".Recivesms">   
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nuts.sensSms"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>



</application>
```

Comment: please post you manifest code

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest file to kill backgroud process

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Note: If you are getting all the running application on your android then you can kill only manually installed application like subway surfer but you can't kill inbuilt android application like launcher of android.

Comment: Thank you Rohit Goswami, After i put this line to manifest file, I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

add permission in your manifest file

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you Syed waqas, After i put this line to manifest file, I got the same Permission Denial error... What can i do.?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESS" ></uses-permission>

Answer (score 0):

Goto your manifest file and add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Soumil Deshpande, After i put this line to manifest file, again i got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the relevant permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

From the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.app.myapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    ...
  </manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you Tejas Kale, After i put this line to manifest file, I got the same Permission Denial error...